# Accuracy of genome size estimation by flow cytometry

Tags: bioinformatics, genomes, flow-cytometry

I'm working on a genome project and using an *in silico* *k*-mer analysis to estimate the size of our genome based on the available Illumina reads. The *k*-mer based estimate is consistent across a wide range of *k* values, but is substantially lower than the previous estimate based on flow cytometry (described in *Experimental procedures* of [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.0962-1075.2004.00514.x)). How accurate are estimations of genome size based on flow cytometry?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and provide information on how exactly the genome size was determined by flow cytometry?

Comment: If I understand the paper correctly, they are using fluorescence of nuclear DNA to estimate the genome size, presumably using a standard curve control, which is very clever and I guess if they do not have any saturation problems in signal detection and if their assumption about fluorescence to DNA size linear relationship holds true (presumably having done a standard curve), and if dense chromosomal areas don't make some kind of odd fluorescent effects then I don't see a major flaw in their work but very interesting and at the same time very simple and potentially high-throughput!

Comment: I don't think your results conflict. k-mer analysis is a measure of genome length, and flow cytometry is a raw measurement of DNA quantity. If I understand k-mer analysis correctly, a diploid or polyploid organism will give the genome length under k-mer analysis, and the genome length * the ploidy under flow cytometry. Are your results close to an integer multiple of their results?

Comment: @JeremyKemball No, it's not near an integer multiple, so it's not a ploidy issue. The reasoning behind the *k*-mer analysis is to identify a sequence that occurs once in the genome and count how many times it occurs as a proxy for coverage. Since that unique sequence is unknown, we instead examine *k*-mer distributions and look for the mode in those distributions.

Comment: Perhaps highly repetitive regions in the genome? Those should stand out in your k-mer analysis, though. If the reads have been filtered to remove hard-to-assemble repetitive regions, that might explain the discrepancy.

Comment: PI and DAPI can be used to approximate genome size. But you would need standards (known cells) and it is not accurate. I guess you can also estimate genome size by enzymatic digestion and capillary electrophoresis (it is just a guess).